# How avoid using group by SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

If I include group by clause in SQL statement,
my index does not work.
Here is the code:

Comment: Use of SUBSTR in the first one for starters

Comment: ?? do you know how to use subquery to avoid using group by clause

Comment: What index are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

The `GROUP BY` clause is not preventing index access.  Indexes aren't used because there's no filtering on the table.  Without any `WHERE` clause, the entire table must be read so there's no point in using an index.  (Indexes are faster for retrieving a small percentage of rows from a table, but full table scans are faster for retrieving a large percentage of rows.)

A covering index *might* help.  If you build an index that contains all the columns used in the statement, Oracle could read from that index like it's a skinny version of the table.

For example:

```
create index purchage_idx on purchase(purchaseno, servicetype, paymenttype, gst);
```

Comment: You are right. Do you know how to forcing the database to use index for the first one

Comment: Forcing, or even allowing an index may require adding a predicate `WHERE SUBSTR(P.RECEIPTNO,1,3) IS NOT NULL`.  Indexes do not contain NULLs, so even if there's a function based index on that expression, Oracle may not think it can use it.  (Apparently Oracle 11 was smart enough to understand an index could be used, as per Bob's answer below.  But in 12.2, a predicate is necessary to get the index working.  Even a hint is not enough.)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to force use of an index in this case you can use a function-based index.  For example, if we go to [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=32d1364b7fe4a2108364ebc3a769805f), set up a table, and run an EXPLAIN PLAN on your first query we get:

```
OPERATION         OPTIONS   OBJECT_NAME  OBJECT_TYPE  OPTIMIZER
SELECT STATEMENT                                      ALL ROWS
FILTER            
HASH              GROUP BY  
TABLE ACCESS      FULL      PURCHASE     TABLE
```

Now we add a function-based index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_PURCHASE_1 ON PURCHASE(SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO,1,3))
```

then run another EXPLAIN PLAN, and here's what we get:

```
OPERATION         OPTIONS          OBJECT_NAME    OBJECT_TYPE  OPTIMIZER
SELECT STATEMENT                                               ALL ROWS
FILTER            
SORT              GROUP BY NOSORT
INDEX             FULL SCAN        IX_PURCHASE_1  INDEX        ANALYZED
```

So you can encourage index usage here by creating the appropriate index.